# Google Drive API - Queries randomly fail on TokenResponseException (Invalid Request/Internal Failure)

Tags: google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I use the .NET Client Library to list all files and folders in different user drives (Files/list request).

The application uses Google Apps Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority and correctly instantiates a Drive service object.

Most of the time, everything works properly and the application is able to fetch the content in Google Drive. However, about one time per day, it randomly fails on an API call (Files/List) and the .NET Client Library throws a **TokenRequestException**.

Here different error messages that I received on a **TokenRequestException**:

- Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponseException: Error:"invalid_request", Description:"", Uri:""
- Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponseException: Error:"internal_failure", Description:"com.google.gaia.client.GaiaRemoteException: Unexpected return code: 13 (backend says: GSS mutation failed: Maximum number of CONDITION_FAILURE (5) is reached.)", Uri:""

I don't understand why the DriveService fails to make the request... it seems to be related to the token...

Does someone know the reason? Why the DriveService throws this type of exception if it's correctly authenticated?

Answer (score 1):

This error means that tokens are being added too quickly for a particular user. Check if your code falls into some crazy loops that request a billion tokens in parallel for the same user.

Feel free to attach some code.

Comment: OK, thanks! I don't think that the code will request a billion tokens in parallel. However, it can make about 15-20 requests/second on the Google Drive API with the same service account. If a request fails, it will be retried by using the exponential backoff. My issue is strange because the same code on the same GDrive source can properly work and sometimes it fails on a TokenRequestException.

Comment: Just to be sure... the Error messages "invalid_request" and "internal_failure" are bound to the same problem? What can cause a billion tokens requests in parallel if the code uses the "DriveService" object?

Comment: Do you use Service Accounts or a regular OAuth 2.0 flow?

Comment: I initialize the DriveService object with the ServiceAccountCredential class with a service account email and the X509 certificate.

Comment: No idea on why this exception occurs the way that I initialize the DriveService object?

Comment: Nothing new @peleyal? It still randonly experiment this issue.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Again... How many calls do you make per second\minute?

Comment: I will confirm with the IT Team because I didn't have directly access to the stats in the Google Console. However, I think that we can make about 32 requests/second to this API.

Comment: I checked with the IT team and we make an average of 21 requests/second and we can have a peak of 32 requests/second like I said.

Comment: All clients use the same key? Maybe it is a good idea to separate those clients to use different keys

Comment: It's the same client. It's a multithreaded application that fetch all drives in our organization. Does the Google Drive API have some limitations?

Comment: Is it something that we should do when we use the delegation of authority, namely to use a different client ID by client/application?